# How to update a label multiple times Asynchronously after a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have a website built on .Net Framework 4.8. I have a button that when clicked it will do remote calls to a server **synchronously** in order. There can be thousands of actions, and each action can take many seconds to response.

Hence, I want a label on the page indicating the current progress such as "1/1000 actions performed" and "Current Action: Boot". How could I achieve this?

Here is a sample code that simulates the scenario:

```html
<asp:Button ID="StartButton_Click" OnClick="StartButton_Click" Text="Start" runat="server"/>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ProgressUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="ProgressLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the handler simulating the remote call:

```cs
protected void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> actions = (List<string>)Enumerable.Repeat("0", 100);
    processItem(actions, 0);
}

private void processItem(List<string> items, int index)
{
    if(index >= items.Count)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        /* Can't update ProgressLabel.Text here,
           because I can't update anything before the page is returned to the client*/
        processItem(items, index + 1);
    }
}
```

The closest I got is to use a TimerControl to perform asyncPostBacks to read the progress and update the labels, but this feels like a workaround and I wonder if there is a better way.

```html
<asp:Button ID="StartButton_Click" OnClick="StartButton_Click" Text="Start" runat="server"/>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="1000" Enabled="false" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ProgressUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="ProgressLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```cs
static currentCount = 0; //updated by processItem

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProgressLabel.Text = $"{currentCount}/{totalCount} actions performed";
}
```

I've also tried to force postbacks and save states in `ViewState`, but this requires automatically triggering postback in the client side, which feels really wrong.

Comment: If you don't want the postback you can do the same thing but using javascipt and an ajax call using the setInterval function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, for 20, or maybe 100? Then fine. However, your post suggested in the 1000+ range. That is a VERY but BEYOND MASSIVE VERY DIFFERENT kind of challenge and computer problem.

Remember, Google, Microsoft and more ask the above type in questions in hiring interviews (questions of the class “how big”, “how far”, “how long”). The reason for such questions is there is a MASSIVE difference between say some progress system on a web page for 20 or even 50 items. But, 1000+ is a WHOLE NEW DIFFERENT kind of problem and challenge.

A web site is VERY unlikely have to run and control a process of 1000+ things to do. A web site might "monitor" how far such a process has progressed, but NOT be responsible for running such code...

***This is NOT a web site type of application anymore.***

And we have to distinguish between "real time" updates and monitoring as apposed to say having some web server code call + run 1000 different processes.

This is much like the difference that we going to every 5 seconds obtain and display a temperature reading from some machine device, or even an outside thermometers value for display.

When one starts talking about 1000+ processes, then we can't know, don't know, and will not know the time it takes for each process to run. And a web site is NOT reliable enough to be responsible for calling that many routines.
However, some kind of polling against such processing makes sense.

So, say for 40 or 75 operations? Then sure, we can do this web based.

However, before we post some simple code that applies to the simple use case?

If you are looking for a real time update?

Then you WOULD DO VERY WELL to adopt SignalR, as that is designed for such types of tasks.

SignalR proves the server a real time web socket connection to the browser. Thus, for say a "chat with friends" type of application, both can type into a web browser, and both can see each others text they are typing in real time.

Hence, SignalR technology also works well for say monitoring devices on the factory floor, or even a simple display of outside temperatures. Thus, for such types of real time updates ***(and for crazy beyond normal cases in which you have 1000+ process to monitor***)?

You can start here with SignalR
(it is designed for these real time update and process monitoring types of problems). SignalR will allow your server-side code even in a loop to update the status into the browser.

So, for your huge, massive and beyond crazy requirement to track 1000+ processing events, then SignalR is the way to go:

Link here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/

However, for the rest of us mere mortals, and a simple processing and update loop?

Say this markup:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

             <asp:Button ID="cmdProcess" runat="server" Text="to hide button" ClientIDMode="Static"
                  OnClick="cmdProcess_Click" style="display:none"  />

                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Start the Reactor"                        
                    ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="btn"
                    OnClientClick="startprocessor('Processing',1,18);return false"
                    />
                <br />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="pStep" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="pSteps" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

                <div id ="MessageArea" style="display:none">

                    <style>
                        .ui-progressbar-value {background: lightskyblue;}
                    </style>

                    <div id="pbar" 
                        style="width:400px">
                    </div>

                    <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
               
        <script>

            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestH);

            function EndRequestH(sender, args) {
                // code here
                lbl = $('#lblmsg')
                if (lbl.text() !== "") {
                    // more processing required
                    $('#MessageArea').show()
                    iStep = $('#pStep').val()
                    iSteps = $('#pSteps').val()
                    lbl.text("(" + iStep + "/" + iSteps + ") " + lbl.text())
                    $('#pbar').progressbar({ value: iStep / iSteps * 100 });
                    $('#cmdProcess').click()
                }
            }

            function startprocessor(sMsg, iStep, iSteps) {
                var mymsg = "(1/" + iSteps + ") " + sMsg
                $('#lblmsg').text(sMsg)
                $('#pStep').val(iStep)
                $('#pSteps').val(iSteps)
                EndRequestH()
            }
        </script>
```

So, we have an update panel, and setup the processing step, and click a button. The code behind runs, and then when done, client-side code checks for next step, and if yes, then clicks the button again.

Code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    
    protected void cmdProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Step = Convert.ToInt32(pStep.Value);
        int Steps = Convert.ToInt32(pSteps.Value);

        switch (Step)
        {
            case 1:
                // code here for step one
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                // if more steps, then setup next message
                pStep.Value = "2";
                lblmsg.Text = "Sending emails...";
                return;

            case 2:
                // code here for step 2
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                pStep.Value = "3";
                lblmsg.Text = "Building Projects for customers...";
                return;

            case 3:
                // code here for step 3 - Building project for custoemrs
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                pStep.Value = "4";
                lblmsg.Text = "Taking pet dog for a walk..";
                return;

            case int n when (n > 3) && (n < Steps):
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                pStep.Value = (Step + 1).ToString();
                lblmsg.Text = "Working, please wait";
                return;

            case int n when (n == Steps):

                // process code here for last step
                Thread.Sleep(1000);


                // we done last step, so stop
                // last step - clear out lbl msg to STOP processing
                lblmsg.Text = ""; // blank message - stop processor
                return;
        }
    }
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

So, the above approach is good for about 20 or maybe 75 process steps. If you require more steps, then you need to adopt a different technology such as SignalR.